# Can't start script on remote server from shared resources

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, powershell-ise

I'm trying to write a script in Power Shell to connect to a remote server and execute a `.bat` file. Since I wanted to do this for more than one server I thought I could place the `.bat` file on another server which shares ist resources and call it from there, but that does not work. When I place the `.bat` file in my temp folder and execute it via the script it works. However trying to execute it from the shared resources does not. Why is that?

Note: I can manually start the process via the Task-Manager that starts the `.bat` file in the shared resources and it works.

script:

```
$CompName = "myotherserver"
$cred = get-credential
$process = get-wmiobject -query "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class WHERE __Class = 'Win32_Process'" -namespace "root\cimv2" -computername $CompName -credential $cred
$results = $process.Create( "cmd.exe `/c \\mysharedresc\temp\started.bat" )
```

started.bat:

```
echo started > c:\temp\started.txt
```

If you need more annotations or Information please ask for it.

*Edit:* Working means for me it creates the `started.txt` in `C:\temp`. Not working means it does not (but in this case there is no error given.)

Comment: Are you seeing this error message: `"CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory."`

Comment: @Squashman Why don't I get this error? Also removing the cmd part does not work.

Comment: @Squashman Manually entering the command in the console aswell as starting a task with it does work fine for me.